# import a database schema from visio to sql server

Tags: sql-server, visio

I am asking for help on how to import a database schema from Visio to SQL Server.

I created a simple star schema in MS Visio, I have put the data types on the threes tables.
I have seen in Google that I can import the schema from the SQL Server to view it in Visio
just like what this reliable link provided:

http://mis.aug.edu/drtmatls/aist3410/Content/VisioDBDiagram.pdf

But what I am aiming for is that I want to do the other way around, I want to import the simple star schema which I created in Visio and put it in the SQL test server for B.I.

Is it possible? How should I do it?